# Prevent non-selected objects from entering edit mode

Tags: edit-mode

Sometimes when I select multiple objects and enter edit mode, other objects will enter edit mode with them - even though I *explicitly* de-selected them. I've been using Blender for years and this has always bothered me.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create multiple objects - no parenting or linking
2. Select all objects with "a"
3. Deselect one or more of the objects with "ctrl + left-click + drag" or "Shift + left-click"
4. Enter edit mode

You should see non-selected objects entering edit mode.

Even when I have nothing selected and my scene statistics indicates 0/n objects selected, then enter edit mode, non-selected objects are still entering edit mode.

Any ideas how to prevent this?

Cheers.

Comment: i would open a bug report for this....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a "kind of" workaround...

and the rule is: you have to see the "active" object, then it works.

So if you deselect the active object and you have just the dark orange lines of the selected objects, it won't work. But if you afterwords click one time another object and it gets the "light orange" markers, it works.

see here:

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Chris, I tried your workaround and it was exactly I needed, much appreciated.

Comment: thank you too and you are welcome!